# C# WebBrowser - Application-wide policies that impact security

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I developed a plugin that works on a 3rd party application. That 3rd party application has the ability to start up two different ways - it can either load up in Winforms mode or it can load up in WPF mode. That application only accepts plugins written for Winforms, and in WPF mode, it just wraps the plugin in a WinFormsAdapter:

[image: Same plugin within Winforms vs. WPF app]

Now, MyPlugin contains a WebBrowser that seems to work pretty reliably in the Winforms mode/app. However, the EXACT same plugin/code in WPF will occasionally trigger security warning popups (e.g. one example was popups about certificate revocation info not being available). These popups in turn can impact the code's ability to work with secure cookies. I suspect the warnings themselves are legitimate and maybe they were bypassed before somehow, but it's puzzling as to why there is any difference at all.

The 3rd party app's developer has told me that there is one piece of their system that implements IHttpSecurity, but it shouldn't have any relation to my plugin. Are there any known policies or settings that are process-wide or application-wide, where the 3rd party dev might be setting something that is influencing the WebBrowser in my plugin?

Comment: Without some code I think it might be difficult to find an answer... Consider including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Isma - I understand it's difficult to answer (which is why I'm posting here). I don't have access to the 3rd party app's code, only to my plugin code, and I have not customized the WebBrowser in any way (all settings are defaulted aside from the URL pointing to the desired remote web page). So I cannot post that example because I cannot consistently reproduce the problem myself. I'm looking for knowledge of related settings that I can ask the 3rd party to go investigate.

Comment: You don't need to include your exact code, just prepare some small example that reproduces the problem in some way, that would help a lot.

Comment: @Isma - as I mentioned, I cannot reproduce the problem. It happens extremely rarely. Everything indicates it's related to something in the parent code (3rd party), but I have absolutely no idea what code could be related, so I cannot provide a reproducible example. The point of all this is that I'm trying to -create- a reproducible example but without knowing potential influencing factors, all you would get is a form with an unmodified WebBrowser component on it.

Comment: The WebBrowser works like IE does.  If you're on a machine and there are policies in place that aren't set in your browser control then they will show up.  This should happen regardless of WinForms or WPF.  It sounds like you should do some more in house testing based on different scenarios to get the underlined issue resolved.  I wouldn't rely on the 3rd party as much; unless you have a strong development integration with them, because the variables are unpredictable; especially since you're dealing with the WebBrowser.